# Google Mock unit testing

Tags: c++, googlemock

I just started working on unit testing (using BOOST framework for testing, but for mocks I have to use Google Mock) and I have this situation :

```
class A
{
  A(){}
  virtual int Method1(int a, int b){return a+b;}
};

class B
{
  static int Method2(int a, int b){ return A().Method1(a,b);}
};
```

Is it possible to do testing of class B, in that way to use mocked Method1 instead of real method, but not to change class B?
I know this would be easy :

```
class B
{
  B(A *a):a_in_b(a){}
  static int Method2(int a, int b){return a_in_b->Mehod1();}
  A *a_in_b;
};
```

Comment: not possible without changing B

Answer (score 1):

you could firstly change your `Class A` into a Singleton, just like :

```
class A
{
    A* Instance();
    virtual int Method1(int a, int b){return a+b;}
    static A* A_instance;
    A(){}
};
A::A_instance = NULL;
```

and then mock `Class A`:

```
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
class MockA : public A
{
    public:
        MOCK_METHOD2(Method1, int(int a, int b));
};
```

and change `A().` into `A::Instance()->` after; then, you can use following methods to let `Class B` calling mock method on runtime:

```
MockA mock;
A::A_instance = &mock;
EXPECT_CALL(mock, Method(_, _))
......(you can decide the times and return values of the mock method)
```

for more information, you can read the gmock cookbook at
http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CookBook

Comment: What part of the Gmock cookbook did you find a section on Singletons?

Answer (score 0):

You could follow the guide on http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/ForDummies to build you a mock of A:

```
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
class MockA : public A
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD2(Method1, int(int a, int b));
};
```

Before calling Method2 in class B make sure B knows the mock of A (assign the variable in B with the Mockobject of A) and execute an EXPECT_CALL:

```
MockA mock;
EXPECT_CALL(mock, Method1(_, _)
    .WillRepeatedly(Return(a + b);
```

Make sure that the variables a and b are valid in the execution context of the test.

Comment: I think this is the answer I described in my question as something that I know it is possible, and this solution means changing class B (I would have to add variable A *a_in_b in my class B). I agree with VJovic, and I think it is not possible to do mocking without changing class  B. I thought gmock is something special, some magic, but it is just simple  polymorphism :)